# Gas consumption: reading from storage vs static?

Tags: gas

I am just wondering how much gas does it cost to read a variable from storage, vs providing a static number instead.

For example

```
uint256 public someNumber = 123;

function doSomething(...) ... {
 .... someNumber * 5 ......
}
```

versus

```
function doSomething(...) ... {
 .... 123 * 5 ......
}
```

How big is the difference(i have no idea/represenation. Is it miniscule or is the change influential and costly)? I want to know whether it's worth having a dynamic variable that could be changed later on, vs a static number to optimize on gas usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 1 the compiler will need to read from storage with the `SLOAD` instruction :

```
PUSH32 storage_slot // 3 gas
SLOAD // 2K gas average (2100 with cold access / 1900 otherwise)
```

In version 2 the compiler will only push the value directly :

```
PUSH32 123 // 3 gas
```

So yeah the difference is substantial, only use storage when you must.

You can check it easily with the following code (I only used assembly to minimize skewing of the gas cost computation by the compiler, you can do it in full solidity and get something similar) :

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract TestGasCost {

    uint256 public someNumber = 123;

    function sload() public view returns (uint256 value, uint256 gasCost) {        
        assembly 
        {
            gasCost := gas()
            let _value := sload(someNumber.slot)
            gasCost := sub(gasCost, gas())

            value := _value
        }

        // Returns value: 123 , gasCost: 2110
    }

    function push() public view returns (uint256 value, uint256 gasCost) { 
        assembly 
        {
            gasCost := gas()
            let _value := 123
            gasCost := sub(gasCost, gas())

            value := _value
        }

        // Returns value: 123, gasCost: 10

    }

}
```

And see again a difference of 2100 gas cost, which is coherent with the cost of a cold storage access with `SLOAD` in the first version. Opcodes gas prices are subject to change, so don't always rely exactly on those values but it is safe to say that storage will always be more expensive than stack by orders of magnitude.